# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near '4'

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, dynamic-sql

```
declare @table_name varchar(50) = '' ;

select 
    @table_name = iif((@YEAR is null) AND (@WEEK is null), 'table1', 'table2')

declare @cmmnd varchar(max) = '' ;

set @cmmnd = 'SELECT B.* 
              INTO #temptable
              FROM [schema1].' + @table_name + ' B WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
              WHERE B.Start <= CAST(' + CAST(@DATE AS varchar(30)) + ' AS DATETIME)
                AND ISNULL(B.End, IIF(B.CrntR = 1, CAST(' + CAST(@DATE AS varchar(30)) + ' AS DATETIME) + 1, CAST('
                + CAST(@DATE AS varchar(30)) + ' AS DATETIME) - 1)) > CAST('  + CAST(@DATE AS varchar(30)) + ' AS DATETIME)';

EXEC (@cmmnd);
```

Why I am getting this error?

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near '4'

I am using SQL Server 2014 version

I tried changing the code, but still get the same error.

Comment: You've tagged this MySQL and Postgres, but described it as Microsoft SQL Server. **Please identify which one you're using**.

Comment: print your query,...you will get the issue

Answer (score 1):

You debug dynamic SQL using the PRINT statement to print the SQL you are about to run - then you can debug it as static SQL. Printing your statement gives:

```
SELECT B.* 
INTO #temptable
FROM [schema1].table1 B WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
WHERE B.Start <= CAST(2022-12-10 AS DATETIME)
AND ISNULL(B.End, IIF(B.CrntR = 1, CAST(2022-12-10 AS DATETIME) + 1, CAST(2022-12-10 AS DATETIME) - 1)) > CAST(2022-12-10 AS DATETIME)
```

Which if you paste into SSMS shows you a lot of syntax errors.

1. You aren't quoting your date strings
2. You aren't escaping the keywords you are using as column names e.g. `Start` and `End`
   The correct query is:

```
set @cmmnd = 'SELECT B.* 
INTO #temptable
FROM [schema1].' + @table_name + ' B WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
WHERE B.[Start] <= CAST(''' + CAST(@DATE AS varchar(30)) + ''' AS datetime)
AND ISNULL(B.[End], DATEADD(day, IIF(B.CrntR = 1, 1, -1), CAST(''' + CAST(@DATE AS varchar(30)) + ''' AS datetime))) > CAST(''' + CAST(@DATE AS varchar(30)) + ''' AS datetime)';
```

Which fixes those 2 issues and simplifies the logic in your `IIF` statement, while using the correct datetime function to add days rather than depending on knowing that `+/-1` refers to days. This returns:

```
SELECT B.* 
INTO #temptable
FROM [schema1].table1 B WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
WHERE B.[Start] <= CAST('2022-12-10' AS datetime)
AND ISNULL(B.[End], DATEADD(day, IIF(B.CrntR = 1, 1, -1), CAST('2022-12-10' AS datetime))) > CAST('2022-12-10' AS datetime)
```

Which parses at least - but I can't test it further than that.

Note: I'm not convinced your logic makes sense, for a certain input (`B.CrntR <> 1`) you are checking whether a constant date of '2022-12-10', minus a day, is greater then itself - but if thats an issue it needs another question.